# Benefits of combinatorial reasoning?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, soft-question

What I usually do instead of counting something, I form a polynomial whose coefficients count it and go from there. If you had to convince someone why they should learn combinatorial reasoning what would you tell them? I've never had to use it in other branches of math, and combinatorial problems always seem a bit contrived anyway. So my main question is:

What good reasons are there for putting in the effort to learn how to reason combinatorially? I am particularly looking for non obvious reasons, such as if it will strengthen my abstract reasoning (due to not always being able to visualize what's going on intuitively (not necessarily geometrically)), etc.

Comment: It makes sense to answer combinatorial questions (probability questions and counting questions in particular) using combinatorial reasoning. It is also the easiest way to answer them in most cases. And most important, it is the most conceivable way to answer them (so that **your** answer is easy **for others** to understand).

Comment: A lot of applications of combinatorics come from theoretical computer science. Why don't you look there?